# Export matrix to geotiff

Tags: matlab, arcgis, projection, geotiff, satellite-image

I am processing Landsat8 data with MATLAB. I am using the [**`loadLandSat8`**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48634-loadlandsat8-metafilename-bandlist-) function to read in the data. I do some calculations and combine the R, G and B bands using:

```
VIS = cat(3,R,G,B)
```

and I also create a matrix of band ratios, `NDWI`

```
NDWI = B-R./(B+R)
```

Now I want to export both `VIS` and `NDWI` so that I can open them in ArcGis. This means that I need to write a geotif file with spatial information.

The `loadLandSat8` function, I referenced above, reads in the following structure (when reading just one band for example):

```
         Filename: '/Users/icepodmacpro/Documents/DEMs/Landsat/LC8023...'
      FileModDate: '28-Jan-2017 11:50:18'
         FileSize: 131282818
           Format: 'tif'
    FormatVersion: []
           Height: 7971
            Width: 8231
         BitDepth: 16
        ColorType: 'grayscale'
        ModelType: 'ModelTypeProjected'
              PCS: ''
       Projection: ''
           MapSys: ''
             Zone: []
     CTProjection: 'CT_PolarStereographic'
         ProjParm: [7x1 double]
       ProjParmId: {7x1 cell}
              GCS: 'WGS 84'
            Datum: 'World Geodetic System 1984'
        Ellipsoid: 'WGS 84'
        SemiMajor: 6378137
        SemiMinor: 6.3568e+06
               PM: 'Greenwich'
PMLongToGreenwich: 0
        UOMLength: 'metre'
UOMLengthInMeters: 1
         UOMAngle: 'degree'
UOMAngleInDegrees: 1
        TiePoints: [1x1 struct]
       PixelScale: [3x1 double]
       SpatialRef: [1x1 map.rasterref.MapPostingsReference]
        RefMatrix: [3x2 double]
      BoundingBox: [2x2 double]
     CornerCoords: [1x1 struct]
     GeoTIFFCodes: [1x1 struct]
      GeoTIFFTags: [1x1 struct]
```

Clearly the information I need is in here. **How do I use this to write `VIS` (or `NDWI`) to a tif or any file with the correct geospatial information so I can view it in ArcGIS?**  Note I do not want VIS to show up as a black and white image. I need all 3 bands.

```
RefMatrix = 
           0         -30
          30           0
      102870     -736770
```

and

GeoTIFFCodes gives a projection code of 32767. I have tried `geotiffwrite` including the reference matrix and the projection code:

```
geotiffwrite('test.tif',VISt,Ref,'CoordRefSysCode',32767)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error using `geotiffwrite`>`validateCoordRefSysCode` (line 718)
>   The '`CoordRefSysCode`' parameter must indicate a geographic or projected
>   coordinate reference system.
>
> Error in `geotiffwrite`>`validateParams` (line 413)
>       `coordRefSysCode = validateCoordRefSysCode(S.CoordRefSysCode);`
>
> Error in `geotiffwrite`>`validateInputs` (line 340)
>   `Params = validateParams(Params);`
>
> Error in `geotiffwrite` (line 235)
>      `[filename, A, cmap, R, Params] = validateInputs( ...`

I have also exported each separate band as ascii text with a header that Arc reads. This works, but I have a lot of images, and I don't want to have to combine all the bands together in Arc.

Comment: 32767 is not a valid EPSG code. Looking at the  data it's WGS84 and therefore the code should be 4326. You probably took the wrong code, the right one is in `GeoTIFFCodes.GCS` i believe (GCS = global coordinate system).